# Visio: catch switching window/document event

Tags: c#, .net, add-in, visio, office-addins

I developed an add in for Visio and I'm having some trouble with catching
certain events. I have a custom ribbon for my add in and what I already can do,
is enabled or disabled (show/hide) it based on the document.

But now I would like to have multiple documents open and check when switching to
another document if the ribbon should be enabled or disabled. However I can not seem to find the right event code for this. I tried the following codes but with no luck:
 - PageChanged
 - WindowChanged
 - BeforeWindowPageTurn
 - WindowTurnedToPage

So concretely what I would like to do is catch the event when one document loses focus and another one gets the focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could listen to the [Application.WindowActivated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Visio-VBA/articles/application-windowactivated-event-visio) event and then in the handler, inspect the ActiveDocument or the window.Document property (in the eventargs) to decide whether it is a document that you're interested in.  You might also want to listen to [DocumentCreated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vba/visio-vba/articles/application-documentcreated-event-visio) and [DocumentOpened](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vba/visio-vba/articles/application-documentopened-event-visio) (on Application) and only start listening to the window event once you know that the application might be handling one of your documents.